# osmosisでセレクタに該当する要素を逐次確認する方法

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

`Ruby`の`Nokogiri`でスクレイピングを書くときには`pry`などで以下のようにすぐにセレクタで選択した要素が何かを確認しながらしていました。

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://google.com').read)
doc.at_css('title')
#=> <title>Google</title>
```

ですが、`NodeJS`の`osmosis`だと`REPL`上で

```
osmosis.get('http://google.com').find('title')
```

だと何も表示されず

```
osmosis.get('http://google.com').find('title')
.set({'title':'text()'})
.data(function(data){console.log(data)});

> { title: 'Google' }
```

とする必要がありました。この方法ですと何が取得できているか逐次確認するのが非常に手間になってしまうのですが、何かもっと良い方法はないでしょうか？

#### 追記

回答がつかなかったため、英語版の方にも質問を投げました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072114/how-to-check-elements-each-time-that-match-a-selector-by-using-osmosis